# SubQueries in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compile a subquery in MSSQL 2012 to extract container volumes in import shipments using the following

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT JobShipment_1.JS_UniqueConsignRef, JobContainer_1.JC_ContainerNum,
                      (SELECT dbo.JobPackLines.JL_ActualVolume
                       FROM      dbo.JobPackLines INNER JOIN
                                         dbo.JobShipment ON dbo.JobPackLines.JL_JS = dbo.JobShipment.JS_PK INNER JOIN
                                         dbo.JobContainerPackPivot ON dbo.JobPackLines.JL_PK = dbo.JobContainerPackPivot.J6_JL INNER JOIN
                                         dbo.JobContainer ON dbo.JobContainerPackPivot.J6_JC = dbo.JobContainer.JC_PK) AS Expr1
FROM     dbo.JobConsol INNER JOIN
                  dbo.JobConShipLink ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.JobShipment AS JobShipment_1 ON dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JS = JobShipment_1.JS_PK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs.JS_PK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.JobContainer AS JobContainer_1 ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = JobContainer_1.JC_JK INNER JOIN
                  dbo.JobDeclaration ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.JobDeclaration.JE_JS
```

But get the following error

> "Error Message: Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I have looked ad nauseum on the web, but cannot find an answer, can anyone help?
Many thanks

Comment: The subquery Expr1 in your SELECT part most likely returns more than 1 value. That is not allowed. The subquery should return exactly 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT JobShipment_1.JS_UniqueConsignRef, JobContainer_1.JC_ContainerNum, 
(SELECT a.JL_ActualVolume 
FROM dbo.JobPackLines a
INNER JOIN dbo.JobShipment b ONa.JL_JS = b.JS_PK 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainerPackPivot c ON a.JL_PK = c.J6_JL 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainer d ON c.J6_JC = d.JC_PK
where b.JS_PK=JobShipment_1.JS_PDK and d.JC_PK=JobContainer_1.JC_PK
) AS Expr1 
FROM dbo.JobConsol 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobConShipLink ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JK 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobShipment AS JobShipment_1 ON dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JS = JobShipment_1.JS_PK 
INNER JOIN dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs.JS_PK 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainer AS JobContainer_1 ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = JobContainer_1.JC_JK 
INNER JOIN dbo.JobDeclaration ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.JobDeclaration.JE_JS
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT JobShipment_1.JS_UniqueConsignRef, JobContainer_1.JC_ContainerNum,
        (SELECT JPL.JL_ActualVolume
        FROM dbo.JobPackLines AS JPL
        INNER JOIN dbo.JobShipment AS JS ON JS.JS_PK = JPL.JL_JS
        INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainerPackPivot AS JCP ON JCP.J6_JL = JPL.JL_PK 
        INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainer AS JC ON JC.JC_PK = JPL.J6_JC) AS Expr1
    FROM  dbo.JobConsol 
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobConShipLink ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JK 
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobShipment AS JobShipment_1 ON dbo.JobConShipLink.JN_JS = JobShipment_1.JS_PK 
    INNER JOIN dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.cvw_JobShipmentOrgs.JS_PK 
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobContainer AS JobContainer_1 ON dbo.JobConsol.JK_PK = JobContainer_1.JC_JK 
    INNER JOIN dbo.JobDeclaration ON JobShipment_1.JS_PK = dbo.JobDeclaration.JE_JS
```